# Having trouble with setup.py

Tags: python, module, setup.py

I've been using python for a while but I can't remember how I used to install modules, I haven't needed to in forever. I recently reinstalled ubuntu so now I need to.

Firstly, I try to run setup.py and get this:

```
nicholas@nicholas-K53E:~$ python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried using synaptic to install BeautifulSoup but it didn't work either and python tells me there's no modules named that.

Some forums said that it had to do with being in the wrong working directory so I cd'd into my Python26 folder and tried to run python ./setup.py install from there and it still didn't work. I'm not sure what the deal is.

Any guidance?

Comment: So to be clear, have you verified that you are trying to run that command from the location of setup.py?

Comment: Often, you can use `easy_install` to fetch and install python packages (although not always).  `easy_install` itself comes with setuptools which you'll need to download, unzip, cd to the toplevel directory and then run `python setup.py install` to properly install...  (although `synaptic` may know about setuptools ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

**OR**

```
sudo aptitude install python-setuptools
```

Then just run:

```
sudo easy_install <module>
```

e.g.

```
sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo aptitude install python-beautifulsoup` should do that for you. Synaptic is alright, but I prefer aptitude for many reasons (CLI is one of them obviously). Most of the modules you want should be available through your package manager, and beautifulsoup should definitely be. If that command does not work for you, there are other issues you need to look at.

You should definitely be able to use [easy_install](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html) for more popular packages and well, and as far as utilizing `setup.py` you need to be in a directory actually containing it. What does `ls | grep setup.py` return for you when you are in the proper working directory? `setup.py` typically comes with a downloaded package, so make sure you are actually in the folder containing that package.

Comment: Also, your sample shows you being in your home directory (`~`). Make sure you are actually in the BeautifulSoup folder you downloaded, otherwise `setup.py` isn't going to actually do anything.

Answer (score 1):

See other answers that recommend using the package manager that comes with Ubuntu (aptitude). This is the easiest way to do it.

However, to answer your specific question, to install a package based on the [Distutils](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#the-new-standard-distutils) you need to download the package, extract it, and then run the setup.py script.

As an example for BeautifulSoup:

Download the package from [Beautiful Soup 4.1.3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/) (at time of writing get the beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz tarball).

```
wget http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz
cd beautifulsoup4-4.1.3
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudo command will not work in Windows.

If you have something to install don't use Sudo, instead directly install your file:

for ex: If you **sudo python3 setup.py install**

then windows users can just type **setup.py install**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows? if so, replace the `python` with `C:\python39\python.exe`  and type in the rest of the command.

Answer (score 0):

The right command is:

```
sudo apt install python-setuptools
```