# How to compile/create python3*.lib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question I have 2 projects that use python 3.4.* and 3.5.*'s /include and /libs folders (just python34.lib and python35.lib). Both versions have entered security releases mode, meaning they are released in source code forms [python35](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-356/) and [python34](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-349/).

My task is to update those 2 version to their latest releases.

And since there is no python34.lib or python35.lib files available from source code release, what do I have to do in order to compile a lib file from source?

I tried to build the PCBuild solution but, there was no installer created nor the lib file got created.

Would it be safe to guess that any security changes that came after a release with official installer would be part of /Include files?

Any help highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried through the command line?

Comment: I am sorry, have I tried what exaclty?

I tried to install it from command line, but I am getting an error I cannot overcome
 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Python-3.4.9\Python-3.4.9\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CFLAGS'] = cflags + ' ' + py_cflags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

I have also tried the built.bat, but what's been built is loads of .obj files.., so still clueless of the right approach to this..

Comment: What are the datatypes of `cflags` and `py_cflags_nodist`? Cause it looks like you are trying to concatenate non string data types. @Kris

Comment: this is from setup.py `cflags = sysconfig.get_config_var('CFLAGS')
py_cflags_nodist = sysconfig.get_config_var('PY_CFLAGS_NODIST')
sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CFLAGS'] = cflags + ' ' + py_cflags_nodist`

Comment: Give what they did on this post a try [Setup.py Install Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083158/having-trouble-with-setup-py)

Another thing I found while trying to lookup solutions was `pip install python --upgrade`.

And another link to an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102943/how-to-update-python) gives a few more command lines to try
Let me know what the if this points you in the right directions or not

Comment: The first link isn't good, as one person pointed at the bottom, sudo is for linux install, the command for windows I already tried with the above error. The next leads me to the same idea I had, I have to build the `\PCBuild` solution from the source files, as painful as it might be using VC10 and all.. this [link](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2015/03/building-python-x64-on-windows-7-with.html) has some more details about building from source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181950/discussion-between-b-cratty-and-kris).